# faster iteration over large dictionary

Tags: python, json, performance, loops

I am currently writing a class object to iterate over a large JSON file (that the Pipeline converts into a nested dictionary of dictionaries) to extract some linguistic features using an API (the API itself and the key have been removed from the code, as they are private). This is what the data looks like after being converted:

```
{0 : {'id': 'a', 'lang': 'en', 'text': 'aaa'}, 1 : {'id': 'b', 'lang': 'nl', 'text': 'bbb'}, 3 : {'id': 'c', 'lang': 'fr', 'text': 'ccc'}}
```

However, when it comes to sentiment analysis, the code takes very long to run. Any suggestion on how the speed could be improved? I thought about `map()` but I am not sure how that would apply here, considering I have a condition and a new key in the original value of the outer dictionary must be created based on that condition.

```
class Pipeline:

    def __init__(self, json_file_path, json_file_path_zip=None, API="--"):
        '''Initializes a Pipeline object.
        INPUT:
        json_file_path: A json file path
        API: the current API'''

        self.API = API
        self.json_file_path = json_file_path
        self.json_file_path_zip = json_file_path + '.zip'
        self.json_file = self.converter(json_file_path_zip)

    
    def converter(self, json_file_path_zip):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.json_file_path_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall()

        with open(self.json_file_path) as ff:
            d = json.load(ff)
        
        json_file = {}
        for i, item in enumerate(d):
            json_file[i] = item
        
        return json_file
    
    
    def add_SENTIMENT(self):
        for key, value in self.json_file.items():
            if value['lang'] in ["en", "es", "ar", "da", "de", "fr", "it", "ja", "nl", "pl", "pt", "ru", "sv", "sw", "zh"]:
                lan = value['lang']
                r = requests.post(f"{self.API}/sentiment", data={'q': value['text'], 'language': lan, 'key': '--'})
                value['sentiment'] = r.json()
            else:
                pass
        return self.json_file
```

The final result should looks something like this:

```
{0 : {'id': 'a', 'lang': 'en', 'text': 'aaa', 'sentiment': 1}, 1 : {'id': 'b', 'lang': 'nl', 'text': 'bbb', 'sentiment': 2}, 3 : {'id': 'c', 'lang': 'fr', 'text': 'ccc', 'sentiment': 3}}
```

Comment: I'd start by timing bits of the code to figure out where the bottleneck is. My guess is the `requests.post` call, but time it first to check.

Comment: Well, have you measured (using a profiler) what the time-consuming part of the code is, to begin with?